# Render view inside block with caching

Tags: views, blocks, caching

My setup is a bit unconventional. I have a view displaying a block, relying on a contextual filter (let's call it product ID). I also have a custom block that renders this view programmatically because I need to include this block in multiple places on the page and I have some custom logic that pulls the actual product ID to call the view with. Basically:

```
$view = Views::getView('view_id'); 
$args = ['product_id' => $whatever_product];
return $view->buildRenderable('views_block_id', $args);
```

The process basically works but, as usual, I'll have problems when there are several such blocks on the page. `Views` only caches using the block id as a cache tag, so the first rendered view gets cached and displayed in all places. Naturally, switching off the cache would work:

```
return $view->buildRenderable('views_block_id', $args, FALSE);
```

but not exactly what I have in mind, I don't want to lose the benefits of caching.

My initial thought was quite simple, let's use custom cache tags in the view, thanks to `views_custom_cache_tag`. So I did, including the argument from the contextual filter:

```
views_block:view_id-views_block_id
custom:{{ arguments.product_id }}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Is there any other way I missed? I can't push new cache tags right before I try to render the view. The usual view hooks don't get called in this case (the second block already gets the cached variant, without even bothering to go near the hooks).

Comment: *Naturally, switching off the cache would work* `return $view->buildRenderable('views_block_id', $args, FALSE);`. If this works then use it. You don't need to cache the rendered result of the View when you are in a block which is cached on its own.

Comment: If I have the same block twice on the page that happens to refer to a different product, well, I won't be very happy if the block caches itself with one of them. :-) Come to think of it, if the block caches itself with its own added instance ID, not just the generic one...

Comment: OK, thanks, if you copy the same to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a block you can switch off caching of the rendered View in [ViewExecutable::buildRenderable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/function/ViewExecutable%3A%3AbuildRenderable):

```
$view->buildRenderable('views_block_id', $args, FALSE)
```

because the rendered result of each block instance is already cached.

By the way, cache tags are not involved when caching variants of the same element. This is only controlled by cache keys and contexts. With cache=FALSE you disable cache keys, but not contexts, which should still bubble up to the block level. If a context is missing, you can set a cache context manually, for example for the route or a url path query arg if the product ID depends on it.

Edit: I've removed the return statement, because it might be necessary to build a real render array with the embedded View.

Comment: In this particular case, it works OK with the return, this is already the last line of the `build()` function. Thanks.

Comment: I have what I _think_ is a similar set-up, except that I should add that my single, custom block may display one _or more_ view blocks. The views are referenced from a multi-value viewfield on the node, and in some cases the same view is referenced with a different display and arguments. In these cases where the same view is referenced more than once, only the first display is used for all of them, and adding the `FALSE` argument to the `buildRenderable` method does not solve this issue.